# Can I delete an object owned by another with a callback from the object to be deleted?

Tags: c++, object, delete-operator

I have one class (`A`) which knows when it should be deleted. I believe an object cannot directly delete itself (i.e., you can't call a destructor from inside it) so I've used a callback.

Here is the pseudo-code of my current solution:

```
class A {
  Owner* owner; // is set in constructor

  A(Owner* ow) : owner(ow) {}
  void willDeleteOurself() {
    owner->deleteObject();
  }
} 

class Owner {
  A* obj;

  Owner() { // e.g. constructor
    obj = new A(this);
  }

  void deleteObject() {
    delete obj;
  }
}
```

I have an object of class `Owner` which owns an object of class `A`. Now, at some point, `obj` "knows" that it should be deleted, and a call of `willDeleteOurself()` occurs. This code seems to work.

Now, my question is this: *Is this a safe way to delete* `obj`*?*

I'm concerned because when the method `deleteObject` returns (reaches `}`), it jumps back to the end of `willDeleteOurself()`, but the object from whence that method was called has been destroyed.

Is this construct safe when I have no more statements referencing `obj` after the call to `owner->deleteObject();`?

**Update**:

Thanks for the answers. I simplified a bit here. I do not have `A* obj;`, but a boost smartpointer (alone and sometimes in a map) to the object. I think if I call `delete this` on the wrapped object, the smartpointer will not recognize that the underlying object is deleted. Is that correct?

As `delete this` (and also my code above) is "dangerous", is there a safer way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An object cannot directly delete itself

There is no particular reason why an object cannot `delete` itself, you have to be careful not to access any member after the object has been deleted, but there are circumstances where it makes sense.

I have done that with some fire-and-forget objects encapsulating a thread or timer. They were not really *owned* by any other object, so they might be created dynamically and *leaked* until they complete their work. Then they would call `delete this;` as the very last operation.

Adding intermediate steps from the point where you *need* (or want) to delete the object and the delete code itself will only make things more complex and harder to maintain. The following code:

```
void willDeleteOurself() {
   delete this;
   // [1]
}
```

is much more explicit and easy to read: from this point on, the object is dead, you cannot use it, do not add code in [1], because the object is dead *now*. If on the other hand, you disguise the `delete` through the callback, then others might see the code and not realize that adding code to [1] is dangerous.

Comment: Yes, you are right, a direct `delete this` is clearer. But as I added in my question, I think that this will not work with smart pointers...

Comment: The issue here is that you have one problem, but you are asking a completely different thing, if management of the resource is handled elsewhere, then it has to be there where it is released, or else you will end up messing up the management of the resource. Now, depending on the specifics of the operation, I have seen that handled by means of the return value of a function, so the object can signal *I am useless from now on* to the caller, that can in turn free the resource.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually just as good as calling `delete this;` in `willDeleteYourself`. It is fine if you do not access any members after the delete.